Electron app is not connecting to backend server after "make"
I have some trouble with electron or electron-forge. In general I have an Angular frontend and a node backend. The frontend make a http request to the backend node server.
Everything works fine when I call electron-forge start. When I build the final app with electron-forge make the app is created and starts. But then the node server is not accessible and the console shows ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
Next strange thing - it works also fine when I start the app via:
open -a "/Volumes/path/electron/out/appname-darwin-arm64/appname.app"

But not when I click on the icon. Then I see ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in the console.
Please does anybody has an idea or some advises?
This is the simplified code:
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, dialog } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const child_process = require('child_process');
const http = require('http');

/**
 * create & configure the electron window
 */
function createWindow() {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1200,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
            contextIsolation: true,
            enableRemoteModule: true,
            nodeIntegration: true,
        },
    });

    // load angular frontend
    const frontendFilePath = path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'dist/browser/index.html');
    console.log('Loading Angular app from:', frontendFilePath);
    mainWindow.loadFile(frontendFilePath);

    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        if (serverProcess) {
            serverProcess.kill();
        }

        app.quit();
    });

    // Handle reloads
    mainWindow.webContents.on('did-fail-load', () => {
        const frontendFilePath = path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'dist/browser/index.html');
        mainWindow.loadFile(frontendFilePath);
    });
}

/**
 *
 */
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    // start backend server
    startBackendServer();

    // Wait for the server to be ready before loading the app
    waitForServerThenLoadApp();
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        waitForServerThenLoadApp();
    }
});

/** ***************************************************************************************************** */

function startBackendServer() {
    const options = {
        detached: true,
        stdio: ['ignore'],
    };

    const serverFilePath = path.resolve(app.getAppPath(), 'backend', 'server.js');
    console.log('Starting Backend app from:', serverFilePath);
    serverProcess = child_process.spawn('node', [serverFilePath], options);

    serverProcess.unref();

    serverProcess.on('error', err => {
        console.error('Failed to start server process:', err);
    });
}

/**
 * check if backend server is running
 *
 * @param {*} callback
 */
function checkServerStatus(callback) {
    const options = {
        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: 3000, // replace with your server's port
        path: '/',
        method: 'GET',
    };

    const req = http.request(options, res => {
        callback(true);
    });

    req.on('error', err => {
        console.error('Server check failed with error:', err.message);
        callback(false);
    });

    req.end();
}

/**
 * wait until the backend server is running
 */
function waitForServerThenLoadApp() {
    checkServerStatus(isRunning => {
        if (isRunning) {
            createWindow();
        } else {
            console.log('Server is not ready yet, retrying in 1 second...');
            setTimeout(waitForServerThenLoadApp, 1000); // Retry after 1 second
        }
    });
}

The forge-config.js:
module.exports = {
    packagerConfig: {
        name: 'appname',
        icon: 'assets/icon.icns',
        extraResources: [
            {
                from: 'backend/',
                to: 'backend/',
                filter: ['**/*'],
            },
        ],
    },
    makers: [
        {
            name: '@electron-forge/maker-zip',
            platforms: ['darwin'],
        },
    ],
};

The preload.js:
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
loadJson: () => ipcRenderer.invoke('load-json'),
saveJson: (data) => ipcRenderer.invoke('save-json', data)
});

backend/server.js
const express = require( 'express' )
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors'); // Import cors middleware
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(cors()); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.json(true);
});


app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/browser/index.html'));
});

// Start Server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});

